# Display conda enviroment in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda

I am trying to set up the conda environment under vs-code. I have set the [python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv3E.png) and unfortunately, there is no environment indication in [vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX5Ex.png)

Do you know how to fix it and correctly configure it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important that your environment is activated before you can use it. If your terminal doesn't show the environement prefix, simply try starting the terminal again. This is especially an issue if you installed the coderunner extension too.

If this doesn't help, try

```
conda init powershell
```

and then restart the terminal.

Comment: after `conda init powershell` there is error messages:: File C:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for helping me and here it is all process fixing:

Appling the command:

`conda init Powershell`

then following [Fix Error PS1 Can Not Be Loaded Because Running Scripts Is Disabled](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-ps1-can-not-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-sys/)

1. `set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
2. `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

Afer I do have [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhrq6.png) at vs-code terminal :)